# Shrinking image to fit div instead of expanding div to fit

Tags: css

I have some CSS with four rows each containing an answer_button and a checkbox div. It looks just how I want it, except when I add the checkbox image it stretches the other divs. I've tried adding border-box, inherit height, changing the grid-template-rows to 25% 25% 25% 25%, object-fit: contain, and every other way I can think of or find online.

This is the code, if you uncomment the checkbox_image_1-checkbox_image_4 on the JavaScript you'll see what I mean. Could anyone help me figure out how to get the checkboxes to shrink to fit the divs while maintaining the aspect ratio?

Here's a working codepen: https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/abWwejZ

And here's the direct code:

```
<div id="screen" class="screen">
  <div id="menu_bar" class="menu-bar">
    <div id="logo" class="logo">
      <img id="logo_image">
    </div>
    <div id="title" class="title">Title</div>
    <div id="menu_button" class="menu-button">
      <img id="menu_image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="display" class="display">
    <div id="speech_bubble" class="speech-bubble">
      <div id="logo_animation" class="logo-animation">
        <img id="logo_animation_image">
      </div>
      <div id="question" class="question resize">
        <div id="question_text" class="question-text">
          <span>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
            ipsum.
            Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
            ipsum.
            Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
            ipsum.
            Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="speech_bubble_middle_bar" class="speech-bubble-middle-bar">
        <input type="text" id="input-text" class="input-text" />
      </div>
      <div id="speech_bubble_bottom_bar" class="speech-bubble-bottom-bar">
        <div id="left_button_container" class="left-button-container">
          <button id="left_button" class="button resize">Wow!</button>
        </div>
        <div id="right_button_container" class="right-button-container">
          <button id="right_button" class="button resize">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom_bar" class="bottom-bar">
      <div id="character" class="character">
        <img id="character_image">
      </div>
      <div id="bottom_display" class="bottom-display">
        <div id="answers_display" class="answers-display">
          <div id="answer_container_1" class="answer-button-1">
            <div id="answer_checkbox_1" class="checkbox">
              <img id="answer_checkbox_1_image" class="checkbox-image">
            </div>
            <div id="answer_button_container_1" class="answer-button-container">
              <button id="answer_button_1" class="button pushable resize">
                <span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="answer_container_2" class="answer-button-2">
            <div id="answer_checkbox_2" class="checkbox">
              <img id="answer_checkbox_2_image" class="checkbox-image">
            </div>
            <div id="answer_container_2" class="answer-button-container">
              <button id="answer_button_2" class="button pushable resize">
                <span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="answer_container_3" class="answer-button-3">
            <div id="answer_checkbox_3" class="checkbox">
              <img id="answer_checkbox_3_image" class="checkbox-image">
            </div>
            <div id="answer_container_3" class="answer-button-container">
              <button id="answer_button_3" class="button pushable resize">
                <span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="answer_container_4" class="answer-button-4">
            <div id="answer_checkbox_4" class="checkbox">
              <img id="answer_checkbox_4_image" class="checkbox-image">
            </div>
            <div id="answer_container_4" class="answer-button-container">
              <button id="answer_button_4" class="button pushable resize">
                <span></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
* {
  outline: none;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -mo-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #311049;
  font-size: 2vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 33.33% 33.33% 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  height: 13.714%;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 95%;
  max-width: 95%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.title {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: clamp(2vw, 8vw, 10vh);
  display: flex;
  top: 0%;
}

.menu-button {
  grid-column: 3/4;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu-button img {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75%;
  max-width: 75%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.display {
  position: relative;
  height: 86.286%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.speech-bubble {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 80% 0% 20%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 61.8%;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 2em;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 15vw;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 4em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -2em;
  margin-bottom: -2em;
  z-index: -1;
}

.logo-animation {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-animation.fadein {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo-animation.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
}

.logo-animation img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.question {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 3vh;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

.question-text {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
  position: relative;
}

.speech-bubble-middle-bar {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  height: 100%;
}

.input-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 2.5em;
  border: 0.25em solid black;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.speech-bubble-bottom-bar {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-button-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 38.2%;
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.left-button-container button {
  width: 100%;
}

.right-button-container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 38.2%;
  right: 0%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.right-button-container button {
  width: 100%;
}

.bottom-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 38.2% 61.8%;
  position: relative;
  height: 38.2%;
  width: 100vw;
  bottom: 0%;
}

.character {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  position: relative;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-y: bottom;
  background-position-x: center;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

.character img {
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 90%;
  bottom: 0%;
  margin-left: 4%;
  margin-right: 4%;
}

.bottom-display {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 5vw;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.answers-display {
  display: none;
  gap: 1%;
  height: 99%;
  max-height: 99%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    auto-fill,
    minmax(clamp(28vw, 45vmin, 35vw), 1fr)
  );
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.answer-button-1 {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  height: 98%;
}

.answer-button-2 {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  height: 98%;
}

.answer-button-3 {
  grid-row: 3/4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  height: 99%;
}

.answer-button-4 {
  grid-row: 4/5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
  height: 99%;
}

.checkbox {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.checkbox-image {
  height: 100%;
}

.answer-button-container {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  padding-left: 5%;
  height: 100%;
}

.answer-button-container button {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.button {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #311049; /*Button Color*/
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: hack;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-size: min(6vw, clamp(1rem, 4.5vh, 4rem));
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: 0.1em 0.2em black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.active {
  transition: 0.1s;
  box-shadow: 0.01em 0.02em black;
  transform: translate(0.05em, 0.1em);
}

.button:active {
  transition: 0.1s;
  box-shadow: 0.01em 0.02em black;
  transform: translate(0.05em, 0.1em);
}

.button:focus .button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0.06em 0.12em black;
  transform: translate(-0.01em, -0.02em);
}

.left-btn::after {
  display: block;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  content: "\2190";
}

.right-btn::after {
  display: block;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  content: "\2192";
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
const left_button = document.getElementById('left_button')
const right_button = document.getElementById('right_button')
const question = document.getElementById('question')
const input_text = document.getElementById('input-text')
const menu_button = document.getElementById('menu_button')
const answers_display = document.getElementById('answers_display')
const answer_button_1 = document.getElementById('answer_button_1')
const answer_button_2 = document.getElementById('answer_button_2')
const answer_button_3 = document.getElementById('answer_button_3')
const answer_button_4 = document.getElementById('answer_button_4')
const answer_checkbox_1 = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_1')
const answer_checkbox_2 = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_2')
const answer_checkbox_3 = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_3')
const answer_checkbox_4 = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_4')
const answer_checkbox_1_image = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_1_image')
const answer_checkbox_2_image = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_2_image')
const answer_checkbox_3_image = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_3_image')
const answer_checkbox_4_image = document.getElementById('answer_checkbox_4_image')
const character = document.getElementById('character')
const character_image = document.getElementById('character_image')
const question_text = document.getElementById('question_text')
const speech_bubble_middle_bar = document.getElementById('speech_bubble_middle_bar')
const speech_bubble_bottom_bar = document.getElementById('speech_bubble_bottom_bar')
const logo_animation = document.getElementById('logo_animation')
const speech_bubble = document.getElementById('speech_bubble')
const logo = document.getElementById('logo')
const logo_image = document.getElementById('logo_image')
const menu_image = document.getElementById('menu_image')
const logo_animation_image = document.getElementById('logo_animation_image')
const title = document.getElementById('title')

var answer_checkbox_dict = {
    '1': answer_checkbox_1,
    '2': answer_checkbox_2,
    '3': answer_checkbox_3,
    '4': answer_checkbox_4
}

showPsyche()

function showPsyche() {
    logo.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    logo.style.opacity = 0
    title.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    title.style.opacity = 0
    var button_array = document.getElementsByClassName("button")
    speech_bubble.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    speech_bubble.style.opacity = 0
    character.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    character.style.opacity = 0
    showButton(left_button, 'Wow', handleStart)
    showButton(right_button, 'Next', handleStart)
    setTimeout(() => {
        logo_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/bhH5xNB.png'
        menu_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/l6GysYf.png'
        logo_animation_image.src = 'https://media2.giphy.com/media/E0SE1bDv0sTbCH4p6V/giphy.gif?cid=790b761143fe1cebe2466c26bfb82fc6b178eb7ecad3874e&rid=giphy.gif'
  character_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/6zX8FA2.png'
        //answer_checkbox_1_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfcJWEL.png'
        //answer_checkbox_2_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfcJWEL.png'
        //answer_checkbox_3_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfcJWEL.png'
        //answer_checkbox_4_image.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfcJWEL.png'
    }, 100)
    setTimeout(() => {
        fadeIn(logo)
        fadeIn(menu_button)
        menu_button.onclick = handleStart
        fadeIn(title)
        fadeIn(speech_bubble)
        fadeIn(character)
        for (var i = 0, length = button_array.length; i < length; i++) {
            button_array[i].style.display = 'inline-block'
        }
        answers_display.style.display = 'grid'
        answers_display.style.visibility = 'visible'
    }, 200)
    showCheckboxes()
    checkboxesResponsive()
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //showLogoAnimation()
    //}, 1000)
}

function showButton(button, text, button_function) {
    button.innerText = text
    button.onclick = button_function
    fadeIn(button)
}

function handleStart() {
}

function fadeIn(element, time = '.25s') {
    console.log('fading in ', element, ' for ', time)
    element.style.transition = time
    element.style.opacity = '1'
    element.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

function showCheckboxes() {
    for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(answer_checkbox_dict)) {
        v.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/WfcJWEL.png'
    }
}

function checkboxesResponsive() {
    for (const [key, checkbox_object] of Object.entries(answer_checkbox_dict)) {
        checkbox_object.onclick = function () {
        }
    }
}
```

Before uncommenting checkboxes:

[image]

After uncommenting checkboxes:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by setting the background image instead of src image.